# How to export correct object from Node.js on Windows 10 machine using NPM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, npm-scripts

As far as I know and as far as it's relevant, there is 2 ways to run project on Windows 10 machine, while passing variables:

1. NODE_ENV=production && npm run dev
2. npm run prod

What's going on here?.. Why first example runs smoothly, while the second - returns `undefined`?..

What I get with second example is `currentEnv = "production"`, but `exportableEnvName = undefined`.

Any ideas how to solve it? And why it happens? Thanks!

**P.S.** I would prefer in not using other packages as a solution.

**Code example:**

config.js

```js
const environments = {};

environments.dev = {
    httpPort: 3000,
    httpsPort: 3001,
}

environments.production = {
    httpPort: 5000,
    httpsPort: 5001,
}

const currentEnv = typeof process.env.NODE_ENV === 'string' ? process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() : '';
const exportableEnvName = typeof environments[currentEnv] === 'object' ? currentEnv : 'dev';

module.exports = environments[exportableEnvName];
```

package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node .",
    "prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production && node ."
  },
}
```

Comment: can you try removing `SET` in package.json and check

Comment: SET is required for WIndows, while on Linux it works only without SET